# Bind “Super (Win) Key” release event (not press) in XFCE

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

Is there a way to set up button-up events in Xfce?

I see several posts unanswered regarding this topic. The thing is, the topics are one year old. Isn't there any moving? No one ever answered the other questions I found. Is there any solution meanwhile?

Comment: You probably want to send this question upstream as ubuntu "just packages" xfce, development / features are added upstream - http://www.xfce.org/ and https://bugzilla.xfce.org/

Comment: tank you very much for the advice!

Comment: This bug seems to be solved, when you use xfce under ubuntu 16.xx